# How to check if react shouldComponentUpdate works correctly

Tags: javascript, dom, reactjs, google-chrome-devtools, state

So I have lots of components and each of them has own `shouldComponentUpdate()` function. Most of them simply compare states based on immutable.js datasets. Some of them compares props. Some of them work with [PureRenderMixin](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/pure-render-mixin.html). But with app's growth new states are added, new props are added, stores change their API and so on. So, at the moment I need something to check what actually going on while developing. I can use Chrome DevTools to review  and visualize where DOM is changed but have no idea how to check if react virtual DOM is changed.

I have an idea to cover `shouldComponentUpdate()`-s with tests but it seems to be a testing overhead as I test each possible state twice: its behavior in my app and its behaviour in `shouldComponentUpdate()`.

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking. Could you clarify your question?

Answer (score 2):

Since I am using base pure component in Este.js, all I need to check updated components is uncomment this: https://github.com/steida/este/blob/fb951cfd3805926c22697486c12bc7ddce3f1ecb/src/client/components/component.react.js#L26